# Copy Paste Loop Based Off Indent Level

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot figure out how to get a loop to run through a set of data based on the indent level of each cell.

Please see attached photo of what the result should look like. [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo2Kp.jpg) I have a source column with data (Column A). That data has some bold headers with an indent level of 0. Those values are worthless to me, they just come in that way as a way to make the data more clear. So we can ignore them.

I would like to loop through the data in Column A, copy and paste into column B the value that have an indent level of 1, and do not have a a prefix inside the "|" characters.

In Column C, I would like to loop through the data, copy and paste the data in column A that has an indent level of one AND the prefix |TE|, but I would like to also strip the prefix, and reset the indent level to 0.

In Column D, I would like to loop through the data, copy and paste the data in column A that has an indent level of one AND the prefix |Sub|, again stripping the prefix, and resetting the indent level to 0.

Ultimately this data will be going to separate tabs, but if I can figure out the indent level syntax, I think I can get it from there.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

```
Sub FindData()

Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B50").ClearContents

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, 1) = ActiveCell.IndentLevel = 0 Then
    Cells(i, 1).Copy _
    Range("B10").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `If Cells(i, 1).IndentLevel = 1 Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a combination of something like below? I am assuming you have headers although your photo does not show any. You can also move `pr` (*paste row*) outside of this to a UDF.

```
Sub FindData()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Concur") '<-- Update
Dim lr As Long, i As Long, pr As Long

ws.Range("B1:B50").ClearContents
lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lr
    If ws.Cells(i, 1).IndentLevel = 1 Then
        If InStr(ws.Cells(i, 1), "|TE|") Then
            pr = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            ws.Range("C" & pr) = Application.Trim(ws.Cells(i, 1))
        ElseIf InStr(ws.Cells(i, 1), "|Sub") Then
            pr = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            ws.Range("D" & pr) = Application.Trim(ws.Cells(i, 1))
        Else
            pr = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            ws.Range("B" & pr) = Application.Trim(ws.Cells(i, 1))
        End If
    End If
Next i

ws.Range("B:D").IndentLevel = 0  

End Sub
```